# Second click on menu toggle doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, toggle

First click to open the menu works fine but the second one just doesn't work. I'm not a coder myself but I'm always trying to fix things myself. I have searched a lot for answers but I'm not even close to solve this. Your help would be very much appreciated

HTML

About
        Services
        Clients
        Contact

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner" >
    <div style="width:33%"><i class="fa fa-bars menu-button" aria-hidden="true" onclick="openbox();" style="position:fixed;cursor:pointer;"></i></div>
    <div class="site-branding" style="width:33%">
        <img id="tempdcenterlogosmall" class=" " src="http://oneandother.london/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/logo-150x150.png" style="text-align:center; width:50px; <?php echo $tempdcenterlogosmall; ?> position:fixed;" />
```

Javascript

```
function openbox(){
        var d = document.getElementById("centralboxdiv");
        d.classList.remove("fadeOut");
        d.classList.remove("animated");
        d.className += " fadeIn animated";
        d.style.display = "flex";
        var d2 = document.getElementById("masthead"); 
        d2.style.display = "none";
        var d3 = document.getElementById("maincenterlogo"); 
        d3.style.display = "none";

        var d4 = document.getElementById("tempdcenterlogosmall");
        d4.classList.remove("fadeInUp");
        d4.classList.remove("animated");
        var d5 = document.getElementById("maincenterlogo");
        d5.classList.remove("fadeOutUp");
        d5.classList.remove("animated");
    }
    function closebox(){
        var d = document.getElementById("centralboxdiv");
        d.classList.remove("fadeIn");
        //d.classList.remove("animated");
        d.className += " fadeOut ";

        var d2 = document.getElementById("masthead"); 
        d2.style.display = "flex";
        var d3 = document.getElementById("maincenterlogo"); 
        d3.style.display = "flex";
        //d.style.display = "none";
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: would you please add a jsfiddle / plunker / codepen link?

Comment: @JossefHarush - it is preferred that the OP would insert a snippet into the question, instead of providing an external site link.

Comment: @evolutionxbox imho my best UX is to see it live on [jsfiddle / plunker / codepen]. The code snippets player on SO is not rich with the features they provide.
i do prefer he will do both putting his code here and provide a link to [jsfiddle / plunker / codepen] in order to see it in action. mainly because his case is a bit complex to imagine without seeing it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in your HTML the menu toggle never gets a chance to call `closebox` function.

I suggest you to use a single toggle function (like the one in jQuery) to handle the toggle action, or some CSS trick.

If you insist on using one open function and one close function, you can try `addEventListener`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would like to mantain the code. Could you show me an example for addEventListener ? Thanks

Comment: 1. define the callback help function, the reason why I use a help function here is to give a closure to hold the status variable: `var toggleCallback = function() { var open = true; return function () { if (open) {console.log('open'); } else {console.log('closed');} open = !open;}}` 2. add event listener to the element you want to click on : `document.getElementById('youIdGoesHere').addEventListener('click', toggleCallback())`